# With limited transfer() gas, is re-entrancy still a concern..?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I’ll qualify my question:

1) Whenever you address.transfer() to another address they take over execution. (eg. famous past hacks).

2) Yes, they can definitely still kill the call with this control by causing a revert.

But, can they ACTUALLY reenter back into your contract and DO anything. My understanding is that gas is limited to around 2300 when you transfer() to another address (contract), so they don’t actually have enough gas to get back into yours and write state or transfer further..

I’ve run tests and done a lot of digging, and this seems to hold true, but there’s still a lot of material out there saying re-entrancy is still a problem..

Answer (score 1):

> There’s still a lot of material out there saying re-entrancy is still a problem.

It *is* a problem in the sense that you can shoot yourself in the foot if you try really hard.

If you:

1. Use construct the subcall manually instead of `transfer()` AND
2. Update your internal accounting variable *after* the send

then you could still get a re-entry vulnerability.

So you need to be aware that it has not been made strictly impossible in the EVM, only that good practices in Solidity will prevent known re-entrancy issues.

Comment: Thanks carver. But from the sounds of what you are saying, if you use transfer() in it's default form then reentrancy can't occur.. You'd have to manually construct a call and send more gas with it right?

Comment: Reentrancy is still possible, there's just not enough gas to sstore a now/changed variable (although setting something to 0 gives you a refund, so you still might be able to do something tricky). Even with `transfer`, I recommend doing the checks-effects-interactions pattern mentioned in Adam's answer. No reason to leave yourself open to future issues.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is pretty much the same as yours. I think the documentation out there tries to hammer this point home, though, because a common mistake early on was to put additional logic in receiving contracts which went above the 2300 gas stipend. When this happened, some would work around it by modifying the sender contracts to use `call` and send more gas which opened up the re-entrancy issue. The original proposal for `transfer` even talks about allowing for forwarding of gas, but that was deemed to dangerous. Obviously, even if you're adhering to the 2300 gas limit, you should follow the [Checks-Effects-Interactions pattern](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/security-considerations.html#use-the-checks-effects-interactions-pattern).